# mysql create partition with index range

Tags: mysql

Let's say I have a table `cars`. and the table has a index column of 'brand' (int).
and currently i have 1-100 brand ids but let say brands are being added pretty often.

I want to create a partition by the brand indexed column, each partition will poses all the cars with a certain brand, and if I insert a new row to cars with a new brand_id it should also have a partition (didn't figure out completely how the partitions works ).
So how do i do it for this existing table.
And why every time I see a partition code in the net, it seems like you should define the ranges like hard coded.

Thanks

Comment: add your create table definition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure it can be done the way you want.

If you want even distribution of data, use `HASH` partitioning and set a count to have many partitions you want. That might be the better option as you could have a brand with only 1 car for instance? Or maybe not?

```
CREATE TABLE cars (
    id INT NOT NULL,
    brand_id INT
)
PARTITION BY HASH(brand_id)
PARTITIONS 10;
```

This will give 10 even sized partitions based on the brand_id

Im note sure how to and even if it is possible to have a new partition per id. When you create a partition by `RANGE`, you define the range per partition, something like this.

```
CREATE TABLE cars (
        id INT NOT NULL,
        brand_id INT

PARTITION BY RANGE (brand_id) (
    PARTITION p0 VALUES LESS THAN (10),
    PARTITION p1 VALUES LESS THAN (25),
    PARTITION p2 VALUES LESS THAN (50),
    PARTITION p3 VALUES LESS THAN (100),
    PARTITION p4 VALUES LESS THAN MAXVALUE
);
```

This will give 5 partitions with different sizes depending on the partiton range settings.

Reference:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/partitioning-range.html
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/partitioning-hash.html

Comment: Thanks, but what if I want the next partitions (100 - 200, 200-300 ...) will be generated automatically? do i have to run some cron job to produce the partitions or does mysql have an option for it?